# Add the value where ever date value is same, In XQuery processor 1.0

Tags: xml, xquery

**Request:**

```
<a>
   <main>
      <key>soa</key>
      <valuedate>34,2015-03-07</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>sob</key>
      <valuedate>34,2015-03-03</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>soa</key>
      <valuedate>3,2015-03-07</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>soa</key>
      <valuedate>6,2015-03-07</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>gros</key>
      <valuedate>4,2015-04-03</valuedate>
   </main>
</a>
```

**Result which i want: key element is soa and date is same(2015-03-07) then value(34+3+6) should be added**

```
 <b>
   <res>
      <key>soa</key>
      <value>43</value>
      <date>2015-03-07</date>
   </res>
   <res>
      <key>sob</key>
      <value>34</value>
      <date>2015-03-03</date>
   </res>
   <res>
      <key>gros</key>
      <value>4</value>
      <date>2015-04-03</date>
   </res>
</b>
```

can anyone tell me how to achieve this.. ?
final response, element `<key>` should also be displayed with its value and the addition of value we do only for `<key>` element having value as "soa"

Comment: HI.You added some code to my sample below.  I have removed it as you were trying to get different results than in your sample.  Please update your original request to show the actual expected output.  Then the sample wil be updated to match the request,  The clarity on the original question is important to keep stackoverlfow useful to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $doc := <a>
   <main>
      <key>soa</key>
      <valuedate>34,2015-03-07</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>sob</key>
      <valuedate>34,2015-03-03</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>soa</key>
      <valuedate>3,2015-03-07</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>soa</key>
      <valuedate>6,2015-03-07</valuedate>
   </main>
   <main>
      <key>gros</key>
      <valuedate>4,2015-04-03</valuedate>
   </main>
</a>

(: split the values :)
let $recs := for $rec in $doc/main
  let $parts := fn:tokenize($rec/valuedate, ',')
  return <rec><count>{$parts[1]}</count><date>{$parts[2]}</date></rec>

return 
<b>
{
  for $res in 
    for $date in fn:distinct-values($recs/date/text())
      return <res>{fn:concat(fn:sum($recs[./date eq $date]/count), ',' , $date)}</res>
    order by xs:integer(fn:tokenize($res, ',')[1]) descending
    return $res
}
</b>
```

Or an alternate way of processing (more dificult to read, but less moving parts)

```
return
<b>
  {
  for $date in fn:distinct-values(for $dates in $doc/main/valuedate/text()
        return fn:tokenize($dates, ',')[2])
      let $sum := fn:sum(for $num in $doc/main[fn:contains(./valuedate, $date)]/valuedate/text()
          return xs:decimal(fn:tokenize($num, ',')[1])
          )
      order by $sum descending
      return <res>{fn:concat($sum, ',' , $date)}</res>
   }
</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wondeful example for using two `group by` conditions. So assuming your XQuery processor handles XQuery 3.0 (where group by was introduced) you can do the following:

```
for $main in /main
let $key := $main/key
let $number := xs:int(tokenize($main/valuedate, ',')[1])
let $date := tokenize($main/valuedate, ',')[2]
group by $key, $date
return <res>{sum($number)},{$date}</res>
```

It will group first by the key and then by the date and using the aggregate function `sum()` calculate the sum accordingly.

Comment: Sorry XQuery 3.0 is not supported.. pls give some other solution.. !

Comment: Well, then please edit your question and add what XQuery processor you are using

Comment: I don't know what version of XQuery processor i am using, but when i tried the above solution it did't worked for me, I am using BEA WorkSpace Studio Version: 1.1,